# fetch value img src jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

whats the proper way to fetch the value of img src trough the following structure. The code below is returning empty.

JS bin (click on smiley): https://jsbin.com/lelaxam/edit?html,js,output

NOTICE: When i remove the A HREF tag around the image i receive the image src, if i place the A HREF tags around IMG i dont receive the IMG SRC

HTML:

```
<td class="sim-row-edit" data-type="testtest" style="padding-right:10px">
<a href="http://crezzur.com" target="_blank">
<img src="https://img.smileys.nl/152/winky.png" alt="" border="0" width="42" height="42" />
</a>
</td>
```

JQUERY:

```
if (big_parent.attr("data-type") == 'testtest') {
$("#sim-edit-testtest .image").val(big_parent.children('img').attr("src"));
$("#sim-edit-testtest .url").val(big_parent.children('a').attr("href"));
```

Comment: None of the selectors really match anything, you can't have an element with an ID of `<img id="sim-edit-testtest .image" src=...` etc

Comment: Indead like@adeneo says, as you look at my jsbin you notice the a href version works , the img part fails for some reason. I have searched and noticed you need to use find in order to find child elements but with no success for me.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - the bin was edited, I copy/pasted the HTML directly from the bin, and then it was `<img id="sim-edit-testtest .image" src=...` where the ID actually had a period in it etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code grabs and display IMG SRC & A HREF like you can see in this example: 
https://jsbin.com/lelaxam/edit?html,js,output

Only issue here is it grabs the FIRST img src if finds, how do i select the img src which i pressed on ?

```
$("#sim-edit-testtest .image").val($('img', 'a').attr("src"));
$("#sim-edit-testtest .url").val(big_parent.children('a').attr("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`jQuery.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to fetch values of `data-` attributes, not `jQuery.attr`.

Once you have successfully selected your image, you can then just use `.attr('src')` as you have above.

You have a problem in your code though, you are trying to get the image incorrectly. Your HTML code shows:

```
<img id="sim-edit-testtest .image" src="https://img.smileys.nl/152/winky.png" alt="" border="0" width="42" height="42" />
```

So `$('#sim-edit-testtest .image').find('img')` is well off the mark. There should be no space between `#sim-edit-testtest` and `.image` in the selector, as it's not a child, it's one element with **both** the class **and** id, and there's no child `img` element, it already *is* the `img` element. Try the code below instead.

```
if ( big_parent.data('type') == 'testtest' ) {
  $('#sim-edit-testtest.image').attr('src');
}
```

Truth be told, having `.image` in the selector is also a bit moot as IDs should already be unique within a page, so it can be simplified further to:

```
if ( big_parent.data('type') == 'testtest' ) {
  $('#sim-edit-testtest').attr('src');
}
```

Comment: I have tried, and still trying your code but i am not really getting any result in my jsbin code.

Comment: I think you're fighting a losing battle by testing against that code. Try cutting back what you are trying to test in the JSBin experiment (or use JSFiddle instead), you can always build up the complexity again after once you've solved your problem. Also **indent** your code! It helps a ton in visualising the DOM tree you are working with.

Comment: i just got it working for a part on https://jsbin.com/lelaxam/edit?html,js,output but only when i remove the A tags, when i remove them it show the image src, if i add the it only show the href url

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this:

```
$('#sim-edit-testtest img').attr('src');
```